# delphi form destroy under citrix

Tags: delphi, citrix

I work on a complex win32 application written in delphi (Delphi 2006).
This application does not officialy support citrix but some of our customer use it under citrix.

The only issue discovered is a big latency when the form is destroy (more than 3s to free the form).

Unfortunatly i'm not able to have more information at this point.
I want to eliminate the Delphi known issue theory before go ahead in my investigations.

So my question is: have anyone already seen latency whith Delphi form free under citrix?

Answer (score 4):

We have a Delphi app that runs under Citrix. You'll hit performance issues whenever you perform local disk access since it has to transfer across the network. Are you saving any configuration information to disk on FormDestroy?

I'd start your search in that area, there's no issues with Delphi and Citrix.

Comment: Disk acces is not the issue, the log we have are showing that the time is taken between the last line of the formdestroy and the end of myform.free call. I'm currently looking on all the components in the form but most of them are simple Delphi components (such as Tbutton). If there are no issues with Delphi components and citrix i'll focus on 3rd party components.

Answer (score 1):

We run several delphi programs under Citrix with no problems. The only performance issue is local access, disk access and local devices.